# centering div position with responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, positioning

I have a div with width 80%, and another with 20%.
the first div has another div relative to it to be centered in the top middle, I tried to add `left: 50;` but not work

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

here is the example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw3hh7th/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `left` to `calc(50% - 30px);` which will center the `.circle` horizontally.

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
|     30px -------·    ·                    |
|                  \ o · o                  |
|                 o |  ·    o               |
|                o<--->·     o              |
|                o     ·     o              |
|                ·o    ·    o·              |
|                ·   o · o   ·              |
|                ·     ·     ·              |
|                ·<---60px-->·              |
|                ·     ·                    |
|<--50% - 30px-->·     ·                    |
|                      ·                    |
|                      ·                    |
|<---------50%-------->·                    |
|                      ·                    |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/Lw3hh7th/1/)

```
.circle {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    right: 50%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

---

To center the `.circle` horizintally and vertically add `top: calc(50% - 30px)` to `.circle`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/Lw3hh7th/3/)

```
.circle {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    top: calc(50% - 30px);
    right: 50%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: why 30px ? what is meaning ?

Comment: @user3003810 - It is the (`width` of the `.circle` / `2`) --------> `60 / 2 = 30`

Answer (score 1):

Setting the second div to use relative positioning with "auto" for the left and right margins ought to work:

```
.circle {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy20yfv1/)

Answer (score 1):

set `negative` `margin-left` to half the `width` of `.circle`

```
.circle {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-30px;
    right: 50%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Lw3hh7th/3/

Answer (score 0):

Make `.circle` `inline-block` and give it proper margin.

```
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.circle {
    margin:-15px auto 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**See updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Lw3hh7th/4/)